# Correct Hardware for a Small Lightweight Robotic Arm

Tags: arduino, robotic-arm

I'm building my first robotic arm and I am new to robotics generally, but I have tried to do some research.

I need to build a robotic arm that will be relatively lightweight and will need to grab things off of the shelf and place them higher up and then return them later. I have attached 3 photos showing the process I am imagining. The first shows the folded arm going to grab the object from the shelf. The second shows the arm extending up and the third shows the arm completely extended and placing the object on top of the shelf. The whole arm will be about 30 inches long and weigh about 3-4 pounds including the object it will be grabbing.

I know that stepper motors are the best route to go but what kind of holding torque will i need for that weight as well as for gripping the weight of the object which is only (120-200 grams)? Also bipolar or unipolar?

For a controller I am sure I need an Arduino but will the Uno be adequate to simultaneously control 6 motors? I don't think so. Any recommendations on one that will or how I can get multiple motors to move in sync? The arm's motions will be repetitive as there will only be so many places on the shelf for the arm to go, say 200 total. The command as to which spot will be sent remotely and I know Arduino has wifi options.

I will also need darlington arrays right? One for each motor?

Am I missing anything in terms of hardware?

Any help you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

[image]